# What fields are available in the GetString method of the SharePoint 2007 ResultTable object?

Tags: sharepoint, search, wss-3.0

I am writing a custom search results page and I want to use some of the metadata available within a ResultsTable object to categorize and mark up my results. I am aware, for example, that if you have ResultTable rt and run rt.GetString(5), you will get a path to the item that matched the search, and if you run rt.GetString(13) you can get a string (containing a numeric value) indicating if the URL points to a binary file. I would like to know what other parameters to this method are possible and what they return. In particular I am hoping that one of the parameters will cause the method to indicate if the search result is a subweb vs a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using the GetName method on the same object I discovered that there are 15 values. The names shed some light on what they are:

```
0: WorkId //eg "867"
1: Rank //eg "861"
2: Title //eg "Untitled Document"
3: Author //eg "System Account"
4: Size //eg "5366"
5: Path //eg "http://myserver:42801/Pages/test.html"
6: Description //blank for me
7: Write //eg "03/17/2010 10:28:29"
8: SiteName //eg "http://myserver:14286"
9: CollapsingStatus //eg "0" no idea what this means
10: HitHighlightedSummary //eg "Test page 2"
11: HitHighlightedProperties //eg "Untitled Documenthttp://myserver:42801/Pages/test.html"
12: ContentClass //eg "STS_ListItem_850"
13: IsDocument //eg "1"
14: PictureThumbnailURL //blank for me
```